# Facebook self profile picture url is valid for limit period of time

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

In my Android app I'm using Facebook SDK (currently 4.33.0) and getting self profile picture. As a response I get url [like this](https://lookaside.facebook.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=1676521992437933&height=200&width=200&ext=1526123988&hash=AeT6vF1thqmEcyOR), formatted:

```
https://lookaside.facebook.com/platform/profilepic/
?asid={appUserId}
&height=200&width=200
&ext={timestamp of validity of the hash, 3 days}
&hash=AeT6vF1thqmEcyOR
```

This approach, obviously, is not pretty convenient, so is there a way to get permanent link to picture of self Facebook profile?

Comment: `https://graph.facebook.com/vX.Y/{user-id}/picture`

Answer (score 0):

I've found out how to get self user picture URI using Facebook SDK:

```
Profile.getCurrentProfile().getProfilePictureUri(200, 200).toString();
```